# StackOverflow error in Spring Integration LoggingHandler

Tags: java, spring-integration, hikaricp

I'm facing some weird stackoverflow error issue with no much details thrown by org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler. This is happening just after termination of flow.
Does anyone have any idea what can be the reason behind what's causing it?

```
{}2022-11-14T21:56:22,176WARN [HikariPool-1 housekeeper]com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1h40m40s250ms340�s500ns).
ERROR[pool-19-thread-1**]org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler:java.lang.StackOverflowError**
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.resolveDestination(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:78)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.send(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:465)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
```

This is happening just after termination of flow at savingLionProcessingRequestToDB

1. I checked there is no I/p channel and the output channel as same and causing some cycle
2. I've debugged the flow after the persistence of data in the termination step ie: in dsl .to(savingLionProcessingRequestToDB()) method, thread is going into starvation phase as mentioned in logs and throwing stackoverflow exceptions

Please find the scatter gather flow below:

```
     @MessagingGateway
public interface LionGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input", replyChannel = "lionReplyChannel")
  Object processlionRequest(
      @Payload Message lionRequest,
      @Header("dbID") Long dbID,
      @Header(value = "reqNumber", required = false) String requestNumber,
}




  //   Main flow

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(saveLionDB())
                        .recipientFlow(preparingRequestFromLionRequest()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(prepareLionRequest()))
            .to(sampleFlow1());



  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow sampleFlow1() {
    return flow ->
        flow.enrichHeaders(h -> h.replyChannel("responseChannel", true))
            .handle(
                Http.outboundGateway(serviceURL, restTemplateConfig.restTemplate())
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("type", "name")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(response.class))
            .handle(lionsService, "lionService1")
            .logAndReply("Response");
  }



Another flow being leveraged further in processing :- 

  @Bean
  @BridgeFrom("responseChannel")
  public MessageChannel lionChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
  }


@Bean
  public IntegrationFlow lionSampleFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(lionChannel())
        .split()
        .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
        .log("payload")
        .scatterGather(
            scatterer ->
                scatterer
                    .applySequence(true)
                    .recipientFlow(getLionResponse())
                    .recipientFlow(prepareResponse()),
            gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(sendLionResponse()))
        .to(savingLionProcessingRequestToDB());
  }

@Bean
  public IntegrationFlow savingLionProcessingRequestToDB() {
    return flow ->
        flow.filter(
                conditionToPersistDBData,
                f -> f.discardFlow(BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge))
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.errorChannel("lionErrorChannel1", true))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.replyChannel(lionReplyChannel(), true))       // defined at gateway layer as the replyChannel 
            .handle(
                (payload, header) ->
                    lionsService.saveLionResponse(
                        header.get("dbID", Long.class),
                        header.get("reqNumber", String.class),
                        header.get("createdAt", Timestamp.class),
            .logAndReply("persist_response");
  }


 public LionModel saveLionResponse(
      long dbId,
      String requestNumber,
      Timestamp createdAt,) {

    
    
    // return lionProcessingRepository.save(lionModel);
    
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please find edited query

Comment: Please, learn how to ask questions over here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You really need to be sure what tags you choose for your problem. I know it is possible to create tags easy, but it doesn't mean that all of them are monitored here.

Comment: Ah, I missed it, thanks for adding that tag.  could you please share inputs on the query?

Comment: Please, share what do you do in that `savingLionProcessingRequestToDB()`? According to the current stack trace, it looks like you are looping your flow some way, since the part of the problem is producing a reply from the handler. What is `I/p channel`? Which channel is causing the cycle?  You need to share more info around your problem. \

Comment: Please find the edited query for the same: 
1) I/p channel for this flow is lionChannel getting a response from the main flow 
2) Cycle is happening at the termination step in the lionSampleFlow after the data is persisted and when the response is returned through savingLionProcessingRequestToDB() method.